# Makefile error from inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a Makefile which looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -std=gnu++11
SOURCES =
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: main.o filelog.o temp.o measobj.o
    g++ -pthread main.o measobj.o filelog.o temp.o -o run

.cpp.o:
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Whereby temp is a subclass from measobj. My problem is know that I get this error when I try to compile it:

```
g++ -pthread main.o measobj.o filelog.o temp.o -o run
measobj.o: In function `MeasObj::MeasObj()':
measobj.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `vtable for MeasObj'
temp.o: In function `.LC6':
temp.cpp:(.rodata+0x8c): undefined reference to `typeinfo for MeasObj'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any Idea how to correct for that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help, but you should definitely (a) remove the `-c` flag from the CFLAGS variable and put it directly into the `.cpp.o` rule, and then (b) add the `$(CFLAGS)` variable to your link line.  It's almost always a bad idea to use different sets of compiler control flags on your compile line vs. your link line (obviously you don't want to put linker-only flags on compile lines or vice versa).

Also, it's wrong to have a rule `all` which builds a target `run`.  Rules should either be phony (typically a rule like `all` is phony) or they should build the target (exactly).  With this makefile if you run `make` then run it again without changing anything, it will still always re-link the `run` command.

If these things don't help, your problem is most likely in your code somewhere, not in the makefile.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I did apply the changes but unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I forgot to define a virtual function. Still doesn't make sense to me that I have to also define a virtual function in the base class. But yeah, thx for your help anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to implement (i.e. define) the function in the base class, then what you want is a **pure virtual function**. Just declare it as e.g. `virtual int foo() = 0;`